# How do I use Msi-Property variable in Msi-Package

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I'm dealing with wix bootstrapper and I stuck on the following point...

In the WXS-file of the bootstrapper i.e in bundle.wxs I set the variable:

```
<Variable Name="InstallFor001" Type="numeric" Value="0" Persisted="yes" />
    <MsiProperty Name="Install001" Value="[InstallFor001]" />
```

In the WXS-file of the wix i.e in product.wxs I set the property:

```
<Property Id="Install001"  Value="0"/>
```

Value of "Install001" would be updated in bootstrapper.
Now In product.wxs, I want to use the value of "Install001" as condition, like this

```
<Condition Level='1'> VersionNT64 = 601 AND Install001</Condition>
```

I tried in this way, but it's failing.
Is this the right way to get the value of Msiproperty, or there is any other way to get it done ?

Comment: `<MsiProperty>` properties must be [public properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370912(v=vs.85).aspx) and be in all uppercase.

Comment: Thank you @Brian,
After modifying, now it works.